# bundle installed cucumber generators not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bundler

I am trying to install cucumber on rails 2.3.11 (gem -v = 1.6.2) with the following Gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'fabrication'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
end
```

Bundle install is successful, but I can't find the 'cucumber' generator.

```
bundle exec script/generate cucumber
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@new_horizons/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails_generator/lookup.rb:212:Warning: Gem::cache is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2011.  Use Gem::source_index.
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@new_horizons/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/rails_generator/lookup.rb:234:Warning: Gem::cache is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2011.  Use Gem::source_index.
Couldn't find 'cucumber' generator
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. I am running:
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.7.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.03

tim

Answer (score 2):

When you're running the generators they are actually running in the `development` environment, not `test`. Therefore these dependencies won't be loaded. Put them in a group like this instead:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  ...
end
```

Secondly, you don't need to specify `cucumber` as well as `cucumber-rails`, as the `cucumber` gem is a dependency of the `cucumber-rails` gem and will be automatically included.

Comment: but still doesn't work after these changes, both: script/generate cucumber:install as well as script/generate cucumber as well as using bundle exec . . . any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

According to the cucumber-rails documentation, the generate command should be `cucumber:install`, not just `cucumber`. It also says it's for Rails 3, not sure if that's true though.

Comment: yeah -- that just gets me: Couldn't find 'cucumber:install' generator both with and without bundle exec

Comment: plus, that is not what i see in these docs: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Ruby-on-Rails

Answer (score 1):

First thought is to upgrade your ruby version. In the long run that will solve more problems as newer gems are becoming dependent on ruby 1.9.2. Install [RVM](https://rvm.io) and use that to manage your different ruby versions and gem sets.

The second thing is to do what the error is saying.

```
gem sources
```

That will show you which souces and gems you have. Something like this:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
```

If you know where you specific gem is being hosted then you can add those sources to the top of your bundler file. Usually all you need is http://rubygems.org/.

But you can also add it directly to your sources with this:

```
gem sources:add `http://rubygems.org/`
```

Comment: i really appreciate your comment, but I don't want to change the production environment right now and i'm not sure 1.9.2 works with 2.3.11. Also, gem sources:add 'http://' does that add sources to my Gemfile, I'm not clear, sorry